# Main Menu Tab Help

Tags: 7, routes

I am able to add a new tab in the Drupal Main Menu however I only want it to display when a user logs in. In other words this tab should not appear on the site until a user is authenticated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a menu item for anonymous users only?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28335/how-to-show-a-menu-item-for-anonymous-users-only) - I know it seems it is the exact opposite, buth both "anonymous" and "authenticated" are simply roles, so if you will switch their places, it will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create another menu and set access to it in User Permissions

Comment: hello and welcome. Please make your answer a bit more substantial. Your post is probably true, but does not touch mixing normal tabs with the ones created with the new menu, and it seems it would be needed to fulfil OPs requirements.

Answer (score -1):

You can go to your page.tpl.php where you print your menu and surround it with this code :

```
    <?php
    global $user;
    if ( in_array('authenticated user', $user->roles)) 
    {
        // print your menu
    }
    ?>
```

This hides the menu if the user is not logged in.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks this did the trick. I am using the BARTIK theme. Should this be moved to another folder after I modify?

Comment: No you don't have to, because the page.tpl.php is specific to your theme.